# Duda imprimir String con formato hora en Java

Tags: java, string

Tengo un programa que recibe de un GPS la hora en este formato: HHmmss.ss y la guardo en un String, quería saber alguna manera de imprimir el String con este formato: HH:mm:ss. Solo necesito imprimir la hora por pantalla

Comment: Nos podrías indicar en que lenguaje estás programando? También bienvenido a [es.so] para entender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio te invito a hacer el [tour] y revisar [ask]

Comment: En java perdon.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat es tu amigo.

Comment: una pregunta tu hora viene en formato HHmmss.ss seria 140000.00 para mostrar 14:00:00... Es lo que quieres lograr??

Comment: Con SimpleDateFormat no lo he conseguido

Comment: Si por ejemplo son las 9 y 2 minutos y 30 segundos te vendría así: "090230.00" o así:"90230.00"?

Comment: Asi: "090230.00"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateFormat formatoOrigen = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss.00");
DateFormat formatoDestino = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date fecha = formatoOrigen.parse("090230.00");
String fechaFormato = formatoDestino.format(fecha);
System.out.println(fechaFormato);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Algo así es lo que buscaba, Gracias.

Comment: Si te sirvió, marca la respuesta como correcta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Siendo que las posiciones de la hora vienen siempre fijas puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
String output = null;
String input = "121516.00";

output = input.substring(0, 2) + ":";
output += input.substring(2, 4) + ":";
output += input.substring(4, 6);

System.out.print(output); //Output -> 12:15:16
```

Comment: Esta es la opción a la que había llegado inicialmente, pero quiero saber si hay otra opción...

Comment: Recomiendo que la próxima pregunta que hagas, indiques que has hecho hasta el momento, para evitar esto.

Comment: Si perdona... y Gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Hola amigo puedes obtener la hora del sistema con el siguiente código, prueba haber si te funciona.

```
 public String hora(){
        return new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a", Locale.US).format(new Date());
    }
```

Te restorna la hora del sistema don `a` es `Am` o `Pm`, espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: La hora ya la tengo.

Comment: Si lo entiendo pero en este ya da el formato que pides.

Comment: Claro pero no se como usar la hora en String que ya tengo

Comment: No es lo que solicita en la pregunta, ya que no sabemos si es la hora actual(que con lo que tu has contestado funcionaría bien) o es una hora pasada o futura, con lo cual no funcionaría correctamente

Comment: La cosa es que yo quiero la hora que me proporciona el GPS, no la del sistema